# Iff and a Switch function

Tags: function, ms-access, switch-statement

I have a `Jobs` form that when I change a value in it, it creates a record in a `JobUpdate` table recording the old and new values each time. It works great.

The text fields and date field are good, but I am having a problem: it has 3 combo boxes that gives me the underlying key and not the value displayed.

Combo Boxes e.g.

Status (FieldName)

- Open = 1
- Pending = 2
- Closed = 3

Phase (FieldName)

- Open = 1
- Review = 2
- Designing = 3

In the `Update` table it has two field where it records the `FieldName` and `FieldValue`.

e.g.

- FieldName=Status, FieldValue=2, meaning Pending, cbo
- FieldName=Phase, FieldValue=2, meaning Review, cbo
- FieldName=12/20/2018, works fine (do nothing), DateField

I created a form for the `Update` table and I want it to show the display value not the key value.

I was thinking of something like this, An Iff and a Switch function, but I have no idea how to write the code.

```
Iff [JobUpdate].[FieldName] = Status, Switch([JobUpdate].[FieldValue]="2",Pending,

Iff [JobUpdate].[FieldName] = Phase, Switch[[JobUpdate].[FieldValue]="2",Review)
```

If the [JobUpdate].[FieldName] is not Status or Phase, just show the value in the field like for the ReviewDate.

Can anybody give me a little help or point in the right direction?

Comment: Edit question to post code that writes data to JobUpdate. Should be able to grab the 'display' value by referencing combobox column index. Index begins with 0 so if the value is in column 2, its index is 1: `Me.comboboxname.Column(1)`.

Comment: The function is IIf, not IFF.

Comment: just in case, try setting the combo box row source and hiding the combo box fieldvalue as shown here: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/comboboxes/bind_index2013.php